# Chave estrangeira pode ser nula no Entity?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Estou com uma dificuldade em um projeto. Criei duas tabelas (**União** e **Escola**), sendo que a `PK` da tabela **União** é `FK` na tabela **Escola**. Porém essa `FK` pode ser nula, ou seja, a **Escola** pode pertencer a uma **União** ou não. Pois bem, eis o meu problema. Gerei o mapeamento no Entity Framework e ao tentar inserir uma Escola sem uma União vinculada, ele dá o seguinte erro: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Aqui tem um problema igual ao seu. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668801/entity-framework-code-first-null-foreign-key

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O problema está quando defines o campo da tua FK.

Terás de definir o campo como aceitando null's, colocando o `?` na chave secundária (denominado de `nullable`):

```
public class Uniao
{
    public int UniaoId { get; set; }
    public int? EscolaId { get; set; }
    public virtual Escola Escola{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Boa 1+ iria colocar agora esta respota.

Comment: Podia deixar a PK no padrão, não? `UniaoId`?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, corrigido